# Accessing std::map with custom struct as key type causes strange behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am trying to access std::map with simple custom key, but while most of the time this works, every once in a while, depending on the values given, it will fail to access the mapped value.

Here I baked a test program, that shows the issue in more detail:

```
 #include <map>
 #include <cstdint>
 #include <cassert>

 struct key_type
 {
   uint32_t       a;
   uint32_t       b;

   bool operator<(const key_type& value) const
   {
     if (value.a < a)
       return true;

     if (value.b < b)
       return true;

     return false;
   } 

   key_type(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) : a(a), b(b)
   {}
 };

 std::map<key_type, int*> test;

 int get_int(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
 {
   if (test.count(key_type(a, b)) == 0)
   {
     int* r = new int;
     assert(r != nullptr);

     key_type key = key_type(a, b);
     test[key] = r;

     assert(test[key] != nullptr);
   }
   return *test[key_type(a,b)];
 }
```

Now I try to call get_int with two different sets of arguments.  The first case works as expected.

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    get_int(2, 4);
    get_int(3, 4);
    get_int(4, 5);
    get_int(2, 1);
    get_int(120, 1);

    return 0;
 }
```

Now if I change the set of values a bit, everything explodes.

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    get_int(2, 4);
    get_int(3, 4);
    get_int(4, 5);
    get_int(120, 1);

    return 0;
 }
```

The "assert(test[key] != nullptr);" fails.  While I can circumvent the actual problem, but I would like to know what happens here under the surface that causes this behaviour?

Comment: Your operator< is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison operator does not make much sense. The complement to

```
(value.a < a)
```

includes also cases where `value.a > a`.

If you make the entire body of the comparison operator:

```
return std::make_pair(a, b) < std::make_pair(value.a, value.b);
```

even better would be to use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
return std::tie(a, b) < std::tie(value.a, value.b);
```

Comment: `std::tie`, great choice.

Comment: @Puppy Thanks! <padding>

Comment: Gah, I was pretty sure that my operator< was the culprit, but I somehow managed to miss this completely.  I found the undefined behaviour there quite interesting, since the size of the map increased, but there was no way to access the elements.  In any case, thanks to both of you.

Comment: @ronchaine Mistakes - they tend to happen... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator<` does not impose a Strict Weak Ordering™. Therefore, your attempt to use the `map` is undefined behaviour.

Basically, the operator doesn't actually produce a single ordering that orders all values of that type.

Consider:

```
   bool operator<(const key_type& value) const
   {
     if (value.a != a)
       return value.a < a;

     if (value.b != b)
       return value.b < b;

     return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ordering is **loosely weak**. Read this [article from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering)  and this [one from Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictOrder.html).

I hope you understand the importance of these articles but regardless look at the following case, according to your algorithm

```
(3,2) < (4,1) returns true
```

and

```
(4,1) < (3,2) returns true
```

the `std::map` requires strong ordering and the above will cause undefined behaviours.

To fix you must do the following

```
if a < value.a return true;
if a > value.a return false;
if b < value.b return true;
return false;
```